# how do I add a gitlab badge with a dynamic branch?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I use a closed gitlab repository. the badge is generated as a job artifact (anybadge). %{default_branch} - master

if the branch is master or develop, then everything is simple. I add a link to the badge in the settings:

```
 https://example.com/%{project_path}/-/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/master.svg?job=badge
```

but I can't configure adding a badge for the "release/1.1" branch. The value 1.1 is constantly changing. I don't want to change the link in the settings every time.

I would like to add a link like this (release*):

```
 https://example.com/%{project_path}/-/jobs/artifacts/release*/raw/release.svg?job=badge
```

Is there any solution for dynamic branches? I will be glad to have any suggestions.

p.s. using the gitlab api badge is a difficult option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Adam Marshall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2307873/adam-marshall) already answered, gitlab currently (to my knowledge) has no native way to do this. You can try to achieve something similar with using an external api for badges, e.g. https://shields.io/ , if your project fulfills the requirements.

Comment: thank you! but I have a private repository. shields only works with public repositories.

Comment: That's what i meant with "fulfills the requirements". i also only use private repos and have yet not found a way for custom badges.

Comment: "and have yet not found a way for custom badges" 

Oh, have you tried "anybadge" (python project for generating badges for your projects) ? good for private repositories

Comment: Anybadge is on my "todo, if one has much free time"-list. Unfortunatly no priority for me.

Answer (score 1):

As of Gitlab 13.9, it doesn't appear that there's a way to do this. I did come across this [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/14389) where someone is requesting a similar feature to what you described, but it was opened 4 years ago and the last activity was 8 months ago asking for a progress update. I would upvote the issue (the thumbsup icon at the top) and enable notifications to stay aware of updates. Also, if you're a paying customer, talking to support to request the feature can help move development along.

Comment: thank you for your answer! maybe it is possible to publish an artifact with a static link, so as not to use the branch name in the address?